# Does this system have an explicit solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$x' = x/\sqrt{1+y^2}, \ y' = \sqrt{1+x^2}.$

I don't know if there was a conventional way to solve convoluted systems like this, but is there a way this system can yield an explicit solution (that isn't a straight line)?

If not that system, what about

$x' = y^2, \ y' = x^2$?

Comment: What do you mean to "solve"? You mean to obtain an expression for $(x,y)$ in terms of $(x',y')$?

Comment: I don't think there is much ambiguity in solving a system, it means by convention to derive the explicit solutions. In this case it is of the $x$ coordinates and $y$ coordinates, either with $y$ as a function of $x$ or in terms of an arbitrary continuous parameter, typically "$t$" for time.. It makes $0$ sense to solve them "in terms of" $(x',y')$ because that solution is already given by the definition of the system presented. At best your interpretation could maybe be a phase portrait, not the explicit parametric or $xy$ solution.

Comment: Ok... So, you might want to give us some more context. Now I see that $x'$ is the derivative of $x$ with respect to some (unmentioned) variable. By the way you posed the question, there was ambiguity. Just trying to help....

Comment: Using prime marks is the convention for derivatives with respect to time, though occasionally changes in coordinate systems in physics contexts. After four prime marks, people typically start using superscripts in rounded braces as $^{(n)}.$

Comment: Well, different conventions in different fields... And actually $\dot{x}$ is preferred for time derivative...
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_derivative
I thought $x'$ was a change of coordinates initially.
Let's put this discussion aside, and let me try to solve your ode.

Comment: In mechanics specifically it is more common to see an overdot. The notation diffuses into other branches of physics through more abstract relations in Lagrangian mechanics, in 3 or 4 dimensional systems.

Comment: @RodrigoAldana is right. I also thought you meant a change of coordinates. There's no mention whatsoever that this is a system of ODEs. Also, if there is only one dependent variable, the notation $x'$ is very often (or even usually) employed. The notation $\dot{x}$ occurs when the need to distinguish the dependent variables arises --  for example in separation with PDEs where one may write $u_{xt}(x,t)$ as $f'(x)\dot{g}(t)$ where $u(x,t)=f(x)g(t)$.

Comment: In control theory you would almost exclusively use $\dot{x}$ even for ODE's. My point is that you have to give context. Different fields, different conventions. In protective geometry and computer vision you would use $'$ almost exclusively for change of coordinates. Stating that the objective was to find the solution of a system of differential equations would have been enough. Fortunately, someone obtained a solution to the ODE system while we were in this pointless discussion. So, happy ending.

Comment: @MPW The tag is ordinary differential equations, so I don't see any other context. Remember, it's *your* community that chooses to be picky about piercing tangential topics as off-topic subjects, so I am sticking to the subject and I am going to assume *your* members do the same.

Comment: Didn’t see the tag, so that’s helpful

Comment: There is a difference between adding context and tagging:
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question
I'm genuinely trying to be helpful here...

Answer (score 2):

If $x=x(t) \ \& \ y=y(t)$ this can be noted : $$\frac{y'}{x'}=\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}=\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}\sqrt{1+y^2}}{x}$$ therefore: $$\frac{\text{d}y}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x}\text{d}x$$ $$\int\frac{\text{d}y}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}=\int\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x}\text{d}x$$ $$\text{arsh}(y)=\sqrt{1+x^2}-\text{arth}\sqrt{1+x^2}+\mathcal{C}$$ $$y=\text{sh}(\sqrt{1+x^2}-\text{arth}\sqrt{1+x^2}+\mathcal{C})$$
where $\text{arsh},\text{arth}$ are [Inverse hyperbolic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_functions)

another example is similar: $$\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}=\left(  \frac{x}{y} \right)^2$$

look: [$u=y/x$ substitutions](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/substitutions.aspx)

Comment: The seond one dosent require a substitution since it's separable.

Comment: Good point! Thank you. Out of habit, I immediately wanted to substitute $u$.

Comment: Yes I see . nice answer. Will upvote it.